# Expand and Collapse feature in LWUIT

Tags: list, lwuit

How can i implement the below feature for a list in LWUIT. Please provide the code for it ...

http://www.designgala.com/demos/collapse-expand-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

See the Tree component in LWUIT and [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Comment: Thanks Shai Almog..Its great to get get reply from u..When is the next version of LWUIT releasing ??.. Just want u ask one thing Can we expect full support for HTML5 in LWUIT in near future ??

Comment: There will never be another version of LWUIT, we left Sun two years ago and no additional resources were allocated. Codename One is the replacement.